# Algorithm for finding close relationships in a social network (Graph theory)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

I need to write an algorithm that, given a social network represented as a graph, finds out if a set of people X form a *close relationship*. This means that every person in X has a relation with each other.

For example if we have the graph:

[image]

The set {H,B,O} form a close friendship since every person in the subgraph is connected to each other.

The set {O,F,K} does not since we can't go from O to F

How would pseudocode for this specific algorithm look like?

Comment: This is known as Clique problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is searching for a [Clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)).

[Bron-Kerbosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) algorithm will find that for you

```
BronKerbosch1(R, P, X):
       if P and X are both empty:
           report R as a maximal clique
       for each vertex v in P:
           BronKerbosch1(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
           P := P \ {v}
           X := X ⋃ {v}
```